# How should I get the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" in "auth0"?

Tags: next.js, auth0

I was getting this error:

[image]

The answer [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-move-from-development-key-to-production-key-for-tenant/62860) says that I should use my own keys, so I copied and pasted the test keys that auth0 has generated, but then I get an error that the keys are not valid, and I also clicked on "How to obtain a Client ID?" but I didn't know what I should do.

[image]

How should I get the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` in `auth0`?

Answer (score 0):

The client ID and client secret (keys) need to come from the provider itself, not Auth0 - For example if you are creating a Google connection then you will need a Google Developer account, create a Google Project where the keys are generated, etc. This is outlined in the docs [here](https://marketplace.auth0.com/integrations/google-social-connection).

Comment: Do the Google client ID and client secret only work in auth0 if I use the public domain?

I was getting an error that my keys are invalid; I thought maybe they only work when I use a public domain.

Comment: Which public domain are you referring to?

Comment: I was talking about the `Allowed Callback URLs http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback` and  `Allowed Logout URLs http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Gotcha - As far as I'm aware localhost should be fine.